# How to check if a folder is deleted in Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

is their a way to check by making an API call to google Drive that if a particular folder/file is Deleted?

Comment: @pinoyyid Deleted. is their a way to check?

Comment: Deleted means deleted. So if you have a record of the file ID, try to GET it, and the GET will fail with a 404 Not Found. If you are monitoring the Changes feed (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list), you will see a tombstone entry commemorating the deletion event.

Comment: @pinoyyid i was checking deletion case if 404 occurred and doing some logic to support that situation. But i wanted to find out if their a way via API call to check for changes occurred on that folder/file. i will check out that change/list request call.

Comment: @pinoyyid your comment is the answer for my question.

Answer (score 2):

use [files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and look at the `labels.trashed` attribute.

Comment: When i trashed a folder and not deleted, i see that in JSON response labels.trashed attribute is still say trashed = false instead of true. I have waited for an hour the response still say trashed=false. After a day passed by the attribute is updating trashed =true. I see this odd behavior. do you see this too?