# When does the files get deleted from Google Drive Service account?

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts

I wanted to know how long does a file in google drive service account stay?

I couldn't find its default expiration time. As I don't have control over the account, how can I know the file is deleted or if no way, Do I have to delete the files from service account myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figured out was that if you delete the file from service account using API(and because service account is the owner of that file), it will be deleted from all the Shared Drive Sections of the users who access the file. Thanks @some1, @MrRebot and @Hadar Ben David for helping me come up with this conclusion.

Comment: Hi, 
So what is then the solution to delete a file on drive that was uploaded with the same serviceaccount ?

Answer (score 2):

since you don't have control over the account, I don't see how you can actually delete the files owned by that account. the file will stay there as long as the owner not deleting it.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375102

> **Put a file in trash**
>
> To remove a file from your Drive, you can put it
>   in your trash. Your file will stay there until you empty your trash.
>
> If you're the owner of the file, others can view it until you
>   permanently delete the file. **If you're not the owner, others can see
>   the file even if you empty your trash.**

Answer (score 1):

It is the same how a user creates a file (no expiration date). To know any changes like if it is deleted, you can check the [Change Feed](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) to [retrieve the changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes).

> Changes: list
>
> - Lists the changes for a user.
>
> Detect Changes
>
> - For Google Drive apps that need to keep track of changes to files, the [Changes collection](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes) provides an efficient way to detect changes to all files, including those that have been shared with a user. The collection works by providing the current state of each file, if and only if the file has changed since a given point in time.

---

You can delete the files **using the Service Account** given that it is the owner of the file. You can also check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994227/how-to-check-if-a-folder-is-deleted-in-google-drive-api) regarding how to check if a file/folder is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The files are there to stay until you delete them yourself.
You can always get the file list from the google drive API (I use V3) and get the files list with their ID and delete whichever you want. You can't yet do it via web interface.

Below is an example is c# on how to get the files list:

```
    public List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> GetFilesList(string SearchQ = null)
    {
        List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> ListOfFiles = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();

        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = _CurrentDriveService.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
        if (SearchQ != null)
        {
            listRequest.Q = SearchQ; //("'PARENT_ID' in parents");
        }
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name,parents,mimeType,size,capabilities,modifiedTime,webViewLink,webContentLink)";
        FileList fileFeedList = listRequest.Execute();

        while (fileFeedList != null)
        {
            foreach (File file in fileFeedList.Files)
            {
                ListOfFiles.Add(file);
            }

            if (fileFeedList.NextPageToken == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            listRequest.PageToken = fileFeedList.NextPageToken;

            fileFeedList = listRequest.Execute();

        }
        return ListOfFiles;

    }
```

and how to delete a particular file:

```
    public bool DeleteFileFromDrive(string FileID) // only to be used when you are the owner of the file. Otherwise it will have no effect.
    {
        try
        {

            FilesResource.GetRequest gr = new FilesResource.GetRequest(_CurrentDriveService, FileID);
            var FileData = gr.Execute();
            if (FileData.MimeType == GoogleDriveMimeTypes.GetFolderMimeTypeString())
            {
                var filesInFolder = GetFilesList("'" + FileID + "' in parents");
                if (filesInFolder.Count > 0)
                {
                    // directory is not empty
                    return false;
                }
            }

            var requestD = _CurrentDriveService.Files.Delete(FileID);

            requestD.Execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Hadar Ben David for your detailed response. I know the calls, but reading all this I should be sure of that if not deleted, files will be stored in service account indefinitely, unless out of storage. Correct? And if the file is shared by service account, so that file also gets stored into the shared user's drive. On deleting from service account, will the file be deleted from the shared user's account as well?

Comment: @Atihska, The service account and the "regular" account are two separate entities. You can store files independently in both accounts.  Also, the service account cannot be reached by web UI. So, if you uploaded files to it via google API you have to delete them also by API. If you decide to share information between them they both obey the sharing policy of google: the owner of a file has full control of it and the file will take disk space in the owner's account. Only the owner can delete the that file. Editor can delete his own access to that file but not the file itself.

Comment: @Atihska, For now the quota of the service account is 15GB and it cannot be upgraded even if you upgrade the regular account.

Comment: I tried deleting a file from api (to delete in service account) using the following code.                              _service.Files.Delete(fileId).Execute();                                               
FilesResource.GetRequest getRequest = _service.Files.Get(fileId);
getRequest.Fields = "files(id)";

File resultFile = getRequest.Execute();

if(resultFile != null)
                Log.DebugFormat("Checking resultFileId: {0}", resultFile.Id);

Comment: @Atihska , I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by checking the file id of the file you have just deleted.

Comment: I got it, I was just trying to test if I get null pointer exception or just the null property in accessing the id that was deleted. Thanks for all your help :-)