# Google Drive upload with a service account always returns 403 (Storage Quota)

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I wrote some logic to upload files into a Google Drive folder which is shared to a service account (uploader@uploadproject-204816.iam.gserviceaccount.com)

The Google Drive itself is associated with my G Suite account.

This worked for  a while, but eventually I started getting this error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The user's Drive storage quota has
>   been exceeded. [403] Errors [ Message[The user's Drive storage quota
>   has been exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[storageQuotaExceeded]
>   Domain[global] ]

Ever since, the upload is not working, getting this error even when uploading a puny file.

Using my real account, I cleaned up all the files owned by the service account, even those that were "unorganized".

The quota to the left says "170MB of 30GB used"

I also waited more than 24hrs.

I think this is about the service account itself, not the drive. But I'm not sure what to check.

I tried inspecting the results of the `About.Get()` method, didn't find anything useful.

```
var cred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(clientEmail)
{
            Scopes = (new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" }).ToList()
}.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

service = new DriveService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey, HttpClientInitializer = cred });
var about = service.About.Get();
```

EDIT:

Turns out I needed to do something else to get more information about the quota

```
var get = service.About.Get();
get.Fields = "*";
var about = get.Execute();
```

Then I can see in `about.StorageQuota`

```
Limit: 16106127360
Usage: 16106125128
```

So indeed, I understand the storage quota error now. The question is, how do I reset these numbers ? All the files the service account uploaded were deleted by MY account in the same location.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to lower the storage usage for the service account, files need to be deleted with the service account as well.

[When does the files get deleted from Google Drive Service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090229/when-does-the-files-get-deleted-from-google-drive-service-account)

Answer (score 1):

you can't delete file created (so owned) by account service with  your real account.

even you did that, you'll not see the files on your real account,but they still on the service account.

you have to delete them with the account service.

below a script explained to delete file with PHP. for this you have to know the ID of files you want to delete. so we make request to get all files IDs contained in folder parent referenced by 0B1-GGKdq5A3qX1dzNkhOLW1VWVU (each file and foler is referenced by unique UID like this), and then make a loop todelete every file.

first create client to connect to service account

```
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

second, get all files in folder referenced by 0B1-GGKdq5A3qX1dzNkhOLW1VWVU

```
$files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array(
                'fields' =>  'files(id, name)',
                'q' => "'0B1-GGKdq5A3qX1dzNkhOLW1VWVU' in parents" , 
);)  ;
$files_list = $files_list->getFiles() ;
```

then make loop to delete all files

```
foreach ($files_list as $file){
        $id = $file->id;
        $resp = $drive_service->files->delete($id);
}
```

Comment: As others have said, a service account is an entirely separate account from a user gmail account. I had the same issue, and i had to read up to figure this out. The error is not about the user gmail account, but it refers to the service account. The service account in only accessible through code. Once i retrieved all of the files from it, i then deleted the ones that i didn't need any more, and saved space. Once i did this, the error was gone.